# What exactly is an Appollonian Gasket?

Tags: group-theory, fractals, mobius-transformation

I've been trying to learn about these fractals and haven't found many good sources, if the explanation I'm looking for is long-winded sources on the subject would also be appreciated. The first thing I don't understand is the idea of a Kleinian group, are these just groups generated by a finite number of mobius transformations? If not, than I'm probably pretty lost and would like that explained first. The second thing is something I've just never heard of: the limit set. Is this the set left invariant under the particular group of mobius transformations? This would be a bit confusing because it would mean that an apollonian gasket is just the julia set of a mobius transformation, and I tried rendering something like that recently and what I got was certainly not a gasket.

Comment: Yes, the limit set is "like" the Julia set but not of a single Moebius transformation but of a group of such transformations. Do you know what the Julia set of a rational function is (the actual definition)? If you do, I can explain the limit set to you.

Comment: @MoisheCohen The Julia Set of a rational function is essentially always its own preimage under the function, right? In other words, the orbit of every point in the julia set under the rational function is inside the set.

Comment: Dear Anon: This is not the definition of the Julia set but its property (invariance under backward iterations). With this "definition" the empty set would always quality. Do you know the actual definition? (Along the lines of "the complement of the domain of regularity, where a point belongs to the domain of regularity if the forward iterations of the functions form a normal family in a sufficiently small neighborhood of this point".)

Comment: @MoisheCohen I am unfamiliar with this definition. I've just researched the term "normal family" and if I understand what it is correctly than for every point in the compliment of the Julia set there is a sequence of functions, $f_n$ which are forward iterations of the rational function and a function $f$ such that the limit of the sequence $|f_n - f|$ is zero for all points on some neighborhood of the point